# How to get url data of form using post method

Tags: wordpress

In wordpress, I'm using a template, which is used to store url data from sender page in database. This task is completed well when I use `GET` method for submitting the form, but when I use `POST`, then the whole `$_POST` array is empty in my template. What is the reason for that and how can I solve it?

Comment: Did you start debugging? What does `var_dump($_REQUEST);` print out?

Comment: Paste your code here .